# Example of a topological space $X$ and a contractible subspace $A$ such that $X$ and $X/A$ aren't homotopy equivalent.

Tags: general-topology, geometric-topology

Can someone find an example of a topological space $X$ and a subspace $A\subset X$ such that:

- $A$ is contractible;
- $X$ and $X/A$ have different homotopy type.

I know it exists but I can't find one. 
Thanks.

Comment: I believe the circle has the desired property, the entire space is not contractible but for a small enough neighborhood it is contractible (that is locally contractible but not contractible).... if I am not missing anything

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can take $X=S^1$ and $A=S^1\setminus\{1\}$. Clearly, $A$ is contractible. Now, $X/A$ is the Sierpinski space and $X$ and $X/A$ are not homotopy-equivalent, because any continuous map $X/A\rightarrow X$ is constant (the two points of $X/A$ cannot be separated by neighborhoods and $X$ is hausdorff, so they must map to the same point in $X$) and $X$ is not contractible.

Comment: @freakish If $X$ and $X/A$ were homotopy-equivalent, we could find two homotopy equivalences $f\colon X\rightarrow X/A$ and $g\colon X/A\rightarrow X$, such that $fg$ is homotopic to $\id_{X/A}$ and $gf$ is homotopic to $\id_X$. But if $g$ is constant, so is $gf$, but if $\id_X$ is homotopic to a constant map, $X$ is contractible. Contradiction, since $X=S^1$.